# Quickfix with several Python strategies

Tags: python-2.7, quickfix

I am having difficulties  to trade several trading strategies written in Python.
I have established FIX connection via Quickfix but I only can send orders if the script of the strategy is inside the Quickfix connection script. Since I have several strategies I really have no idea how to send the order from a separate script. Can someone give me some solution?

```
import sys
import datetime
import time
import quickfix as fix


class Application(fix.Application):
    orderID = 0
    execID = 0
    def gen_ord_id(self):
        global orderID
        orderID+=1
        return orderID

    def onCreate(self, sessionID):
        return

    def onLogon(self, sessionID):
        self.sessionID = sessionID
        print ("Successful Logon to session '%s'." % sessionID.toString())
        return

    def onLogout(self, sessionID):
        return

    def toAdmin(self, message, sessionID):
        username = fix.Username("username")
        mypass = fix.Password("password")
        mycompid = fix.TargetSubID("targetsubid")
        message.setField(username)
        message.setField(mypass)
        message.setField(mycompid)

    def fromAdmin(self, message, sessionID):         
        TradeID = fix.TradingSessionID
        message.getField(TradeID)
        return

    def toApp(self, sessionID, message):
        print "Sent the following message: %s" % message.toString()
        return

    def fromApp(self, message, sessionID):
        print "Received the following message: %s" % message.toString()
        return

    def genOrderID(self):
        self.orderID = self.orderID + 1
        return `self.orderID`

    def genExecID(self):
        self.execID = self.execID + 1
        return `self.execID`

    def put_order(self, sessionID, myinstrument, myquantity):
        self.myinstrument = myinstrument
        self.myquantity = myquantity
        print("Creating the following order: ")
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        nextID = today.strftime("%m%d%Y%H%M%S%f")
        trade = fix.Message()
        trade.getHeader().setField(fix.StringField(8, "FIX.4.4"))
        trade.getHeader().setField(fix.MsgType(fix.MsgType_NewOrderSingle))
        trade.setField(fix.ClOrdID(nextID)) #11=Unique order
        trade.getHeader().setField(fix.Account("account"))
        trade.getHeader().setField(fix.TargetSubID("targetsubid"))
        trade.setField(fix.Symbol(myinstrument)) #55=SMBL ?
        trade.setField(fix.TransactTime())
        trade.setField(fix.CharField(54, fix.Side_BUY))
        trade.setField(fix.OrdType(fix.OrdType_MARKET))  # 40=2 Limit order
        trade.setField(fix.OrderQty(myquantity))  # 38=100
        print trade.toString()
        fix.Session.sendToTarget(trade, self.sessionID)


try:
     file = sys.argv[1]
     settings = fix.SessionSettings(file)
     application = Application()
     storeFactory = fix.FileStoreFactory(settings)
     logFactory = fix.ScreenLogFactory(settings)
     initiator = fix.SocketInitiator(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)
     initiator.start()

   while 1:
       time.sleep(1)

       if input == '1':
           print "Putin Order"
           application.put_order(fix.Application)          
       if input == '2':
           sys.exit(0)
       if input == 'd':
           import pdb
           pdb.set_trace()
       else:
           print "Valid input is 1 for order, 2 for exit"

except (fix.ConfigError, fix.RuntimeError) as e:
  print e
```

This is my initator app. My question is can I update the following values from another python script:
trade.setField(fix.Symbol(myinstrument)) 
trade.setField(fix.OrderQty(myquantity))

So I want to change myinstrument and myquantity from another python script and force the initiator to execute the following command application.put_order(fix.Application) with the new values. My question is is this possible at all?

Comment: You probably need to elaborate bit more. And nobody can give a solution, they can only suggest.

Comment: I have one Python script that acts like connector/initiator to my broker. My question is how can I put orders from another python script to my broker using the existing connection that was established by the connector/initiator?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an internal messaging layer that QuickFIX subscribes to, and that your separate Python scripts publish orders to. It's about workflow design. Try something like [VertX](http://vertx.io/) as that can be setup using Python.